# GridView100% Browser Width with horizontal scoll

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, styles

```
<div style="height: 400px; width 100%; overflow: scroll;">
    <GridView>
    </GridView>
</div>
```

I'm using the code above. I want the gridview to be the width of the browser but have a horizontal-scroll bar to slide across to see the rest of the columns (not a browser scroll bar). The height works perfectly. It is 400px tall and has a vertical scroll bar on the gridview to see the rest of the rows but the gridview goes wider than the browser and does not have a scroll bar. The browser instead has a scroll bar.

Found some solutions but they did not work for me such as adding a width to the gridview and using a fixed width which works but I want it to scale to the browser width.

Hope someone can give me a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `position:relative` to your div container and then position your grid view absolutely, you should achieve what you want

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jdhM7/)

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:800px;height:400px">
<GridView>
    </GridView>
</div>
```